# CScrollBar paint when mouse moved over it

Tags: mfc

ScrollBar used in MFC gets highlighted (and changes color) when i move mouse over it.
I want to stop this functionality.
How can i do it?
What is the message that gets triggered when mouse is moved over a scroll?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all not all version of window changes the color of scroll bar while mouse move. If you notice you will not found this feature in window XP.

Now its strange why are you want to change the color of scrollbar I am not understand.

but as you want

> What is the message that gets triggered when mouse is moved over a
>   scroll?

Its WM_NCMOUSEMOVE message called when mouse move over the scroll bar because scrollbar is also non client area.

For more information on this you may referred this link,
[MFC MDI issue : Detecting mouse move over scroll bar](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/30f057bf-fa3b-478b-9fe1-e90a13d945a2/mfc-mdi-issue-detecting-mouse-move-over-scroll-bar)

Comment: thanks..i used WM_NCMOUSEMOVE along with OnNCMouseMove function. My aim wasn't to change the color of scroll bar,but to prevent repaint of scroll bar on mouse move. The repainting was interfering with a window (lets say CwndZoom) i had created (i am calling moveWindow for CwndZoom everytime the mouse moves) .